# jquery Full calendar and shadowbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar, lightbox, shadowbox

How to call a shadow box in full calendar.. assuming I do have an event and when the user(client browser) click on that event it will call the shadow box or light box... any idea would help..  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Override the [eventClick](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/) callback and open the shadow/lightbox with that events data.

Here's a contrived example:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        Shadowbox.open({
            content: '<div id="event-msg">Welcome to event #' + event.id + '!</div>',
            player: 'html',
            title: 'My Event'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: actually sir I'm new with this one.. could you give me a sample event Click code to call the shadowbox or lightbox :).. thanks in advance

Comment: @Rosque:  Updated with example

Comment: Right now I'm studying this full calendar...how about 2 different day events if you click the 1st one it will display an alertbox.. and for the second one will display the shadow box overlay... hope you could help me in studying this one....

Comment: Key what you do with it by data found in the event object that's passed in.

Comment: You're very welcome.  When you get a chance upvote/mark this answer as accepted to indicate to future browsers that it solved your problem (and give me some awesome e-points).